# string.gsub return as a distinct variable for each replace result

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

Input:

```
stringdata = '{"abcd://ipaddress/directory1/Images/subfolder/Image0.png","abcd://ipaddress/directory1/Images/subfolder/Image1.png","abcd://ipaddress/directory1/Images/subfolder/Image2.png","abcd://ipaddress/directory1/Images/subfolder/Image3.png","abcd://ipaddress/directory1/Images/subfolder/Image4.png"}'
```

Source Code

```
string.gsub(stringdata, "(.....................%w%w................................%w)",print)
```

Current output:

```
abcd://ipaddress/directory1/Images/subfolder/Image0.png
abcd://ipaddress/directory1/Images/subfolder/Image1.png
abcd://ipaddress/directory1/Images/subfolder/Image2.png
abcd://ipaddress/directory1/Images/subfolder/Image3.png
abcd://ipaddress/directory1/Images/subfolder/Image4.png
```

Expected output (where each of the below could be stored in a different variable)

```
directory1/Images/subfolder/Image0.png    
directory1/Images/subfolder/Image1.png   
directory1/Images/subfolder/Image2.png   
directory1/Images/subfolder/Image3.png    
directory1/Images/subfolder/Image4.png
```

Comment: whats wrong with the question? why down voted?

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is since you don't even ask a question. What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve? What led you to using that pattern? Describing the desired output isn't the same as describing the problem. And honestly, I'm not even sure what the title of your question has to do with anything.

Comment: ok, I ll do revise the entire question and post it again (when I get some time) which will be understandable for all and esp this community members. So that all will be benefited out of it. (I kept is simpler so that everyone will understand easily by just looking at it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With so many `.` in your pattern, it's hard to read and unclear what's your purpose.

Instead, use a pattern that's specific to the format:

```
string.gsub(stringdata, "%w+://%w+/(%w+/%w+/%w+/%w+%.png)", print)
```

In this way, it's much more clear what each `%w+` represents.

---

To store the result, you are using the wrong function. `string.gsub` is used for substitution, use `string.gmatch` instead:

```
for m in string.gmatch(stringdata, "%w+://%w+/(%w+/%w+/%w+/%w+%.png)") do
  print(m)
  -- do whatever with m
end
```

Comment: There are so many dots because lua doesn't makes it simpler to understand. and more over... your solution just prints and not storing in a different variable.. however thank you for suggesting... i realized the usage of characters inside pattern in `gsub` before reading your comment.

Comment: Sorry, `m` is not printing anything! `m = '' for m in string.gmatch(radarimgs, "%w+://%w+/(%w+/%w+/%w+/%w+%.png)") do print(type(m)) end print(type(m)) print(string.len(m))`
`

Comment: ok. I got it. When I replace the word ipaddress to the actual ip address which is xx.xxx.xx.xx net and sub-net. It yields nothing. I trying to change the pattern... `for m in string.gmatch(stringdata,"%w+://%d.+/(%w+/%w+/%w+/%w+%.png)") do  print(m)end` -> I did like this and I am getting only the last value! I need all values! I am trying to collect it in a table.

Comment: `collect = {} for m in string.gmatch(stringdata, %w+://%d.+/(%w+/%w+/%w+/%w+%.png)") do  table.insert(collect,m)
  print(collect[3])end` This prints `nil`. can you guide!

Comment: `collect = {} for m in string.gmatch(stringdata, %w+://%d.+/(%w+/%w+/%w+/%w+%.png)") do table.insert(collect,m) print(collect[3])end` This stores only the last value which means the pattern matches only the last value.